# Using javascript to launch multiple URL's based on seperate input buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First time posting here.

Also - I'm fairly new to javascript programming, it's my first semester in college, so go easy on me.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to create, I made this fiddle and got it working ok: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nerdist/5KKUA

**the html**

```
<input type="text" id="TextBox" />
<input type="button" value="Launch" onclick="Launch('http://farm1/sites/')" />
<input type="button" value="Access" onclick="Access('http://farm1/sites/')" />
```

**the js**

```
function Launch(URL) {
    SiteNumber = document.getElementById('TextBox').value;
    window.alert(URL + SiteNumber);
}

function Access(URL) {
    SiteNumber = document.getElementById('TextBox').value;
    window.alert(URL + SiteNumber + "/_layouts/accessdenied.aspx");
}
```

The window.alert is only for testing I did on the fiddle, e.g. for the second function I would substitute with something like:

```
window.location = URL + SiteNumber + "/_layouts/accessdenied.aspx";
```

My Goal here is to be able to drop a site ID into the text field, and based on the button clicked either be taken to the main website, or (when clicking the other button) be taken to an access page to request access to that site.

So here's my problem - I need to create multiple sets like this on a page for a project I'm working on (about 30 different sets...) and I realize that creating multiple sets using the same js will not work since it's using an ID which is unique, and I'd rather not use a dozen hardcoded js's to get this thing working.

I've tried using getElementByClassName and haven't been able to get it working correctly, and I finally gave up on that.

I figured I'm probably doing this the hard way and wanted to see if I could get some advice. I've done a lot of post searching, but still being fairly new to js some of it is still over my head. I'm also not against using jquery, but I have no experience thus far with it.

Thanks in advance for any tips provided.

Comment: why do you have 2 buttons launch and access for the same buttons? what do you mean by access page? on clicking a button user should go to that site or am i missing something?

Comment: the second button launches the same url, but with added directory information taking it to a site access page. this is sharepoint based. this is going to be part of a dashboard page, so there will be multiple buttons per URL input box that takes you to different areas per site like access denied, workflow history, and all people listing. This is why there are multiple buttons (controlled by js), because it tacks on separate information onto the end of the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding exactly what you want to do, but would simply passing another variable into the Launch/Access functions work?  Adjusting your fiddle to something like this shows what I mean:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="TextBox1" />
<input type="button" value="Launch" onclick="Launch('http://farm1/sites/', 1)" />
<input type="button" value="Access" onclick="Access('http://farm1/sites/',1)" />
<input type="text" id="TextBox2" />
<input type="button" value="Launch" onclick="Launch('http://farm1/sites/',2)" />
<input type="button" value="Access" onclick="Access('http://farm1/sites/',2)" />
```

Notice the extra param in the function call and the IDs of the TextBoxes

You can then use that in the JS to build the right ID:

```
function Launch(URL, unique) {
    SiteNumber = document.getElementById('TextBox' + unique).value;
    window.alert(URL + SiteNumber);
}

function Access(URL, unique) {
    SiteNumber = document.getElementById('TextBox' + unique).value;
    window.alert(URL + SiteNumber + "/_layouts/accessdenied.aspx");
}
```

If that isn't what you need, please clarify your intention.

Dave

Comment: this was exactly what i was needing. i was close but didn't think about passing another parameter to make the ID unique. TIL. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quiet sure if this is your answer, but you may add custom attributes on your buttons or your input textboxes.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="TextBox" name="TextBox" />
<input type="text" id="TextBox2" name="TextBox2" />
<input type="button" value="Launch" custominputbox="TextBox" customurl="http://farm1/sites/" onclick="launchAccessUrl(this)" />
<input type="button" value="Access" custominputbox="TextBox2" customurl="http://farm1/sites/" onclick="launchAccessUrl(this)" />
```

JS

```
function launchAccessUrl(input)
{
    var customInputBoxId = input.getAttribute("custominputbox");
    if(customInputBoxId)
    {
        var siteUrl = input.getAttribute("customurl");
        var customInputBoxValue = document.getElementById(customInputBoxId).value;
        alert(customInputBoxValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: i'll have to learn some more on creating custom attributes (still have a lot of javascript to learn) thanks for the help!